# Is it a best practice to always use a concrete type (List, Tuple, etc.) for a return value instead of an abstract type (Sequence, Iterable)?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I've read somewhere that it's a best practice to type the return value with a concrete type, but despite all my efforts can't find the resource where I read that...
There an answer on SO at the very least. Looked at the PEPs and mypy documentation but can't find it...

Comment: Not sure. I usually try to go for a "as concrete as practical" for any given situation.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, use the most specific type that's consistent across all your possible return values. Some methods would return a different type depending on the parameter type (e.g. a method that returns `list` when given lists, and `tuple` when given tuples), and in those cases they'd have to list their return type as something that encompasses both. But giving a more specific return type is always an advantage - a `list` still qualifies as an `Iterable`, after all, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: The rule that I've always heard and followed is "most specific when returning, and as broad as possible when accepting". The caller should be allowed to pass in any compatible structure, while also being able to rely on the type being given to them.

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159957/return-interface-or-class

Comment: I agree that you should annotate your return as specifically as possible, usually. One reason you _might_ want to annotate less specifically would be to reserve the right to change the return in the future while still fulfilling the original type signature.  Now that being said, if you annotate your return as a `Sequence` but return a `list`, people are going to use it as a list and their code will break if you later change it to a `tuple`.  The annotation will be cold comfort to them at that point.

Comment: You should annotate the return type as specific as you can. Think about it the other way, if you favor less specific types over specific ones, then annotating with `Any` becomes the best option, but obviously that's not useful (for the users of your function; for you as the developer it doesn't make a difference (unless you are your own function's user)). With parameter types it's different, you should indicate the *minimal requirements* that you expect from the arguments in order to work within your function (as the developer, you very much care about the *functionality* of the arguments).

Comment: @a_guest, your example commits the fallacy of the excluded middle. If there were a rule that you should always be maximally specific or maximally abstract, you'd be right to raise that concern about maximum abstraction. But the question isn't about maximum abstraction. It's about *just enough* abstraction to convey the intended purpose of the function without clouding the issue with implementation details.

Comment: @Josiah I think that really depends whether you define an interface (Protocol, etc) or a concrete method. Sure, for the interface the same ideas as for function parameters apply (i.e. as broad as possible), but for a concrete method, it's best to indicate the type that is actually returned (a specific type includes the properties of a more abstract one).

Answer (score 1):

Your type annotations should express your intentended commitments, and no more.

Anything which you consider an implementation detail and reserve the right to change should be annotated to maintain that encapsulation. Parameters should be annotated as the most general thing you want to **commit** to accepting. Return values should be annotated as the most specific thing you want to **commit** to your return value allowing.

Suppose that you have some code doing brute force factorisation, and this includes a class which produces some candidate prime numbers to loop through. Initially, you store the first 100 candidates in a list and expose them like so:

```
def primes(self):
    return self._internal_primes
```

You could annotate that as `List` or as `Sequence`, because `self._internal_primes` is both of those. But you shouldn't.

The foremost reason that you shouldn't is the most philosophical. The intended purpose of this method is to supply some candidate primes to loop over. `Iterable[int]` is the right thing to convey that purpose, irrespective of what happens under the hood.

The second reason is encapsulation and the associated flexibility. You didn't intend to commit to exposing a private list as your implementation. Maybe you anticipate rewriting `primes` in future as an on-demand generator implementing a sieve. Commiting to `List` now means you'd have to break your interface promise to do so.

The third reason is that even if you never expect to change the implementation, you may not want to advertise the full capabilities of that implementation. For example, lists can be mutated. If you promise someone it's a list, you also promise that they can mutate it. There is simply nothing good to gain by allowing someone to write `p.primes()[2] = 72`. By exposing an interface which doesn't even have the mutation methods, such a mistake becomes much less likely to slip through undetected.

Comment: `__iter__` must return an `Iterator` and not an `Iterable`. Returning an `Iterable` will cause a type error.

Comment: Good point @Wombatz. I've noted the mistake in an edit pending a chance to fix it properly.